# Chapter 9 Authorization Test Fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, railstutorial.org

In section 9.2.1 of Michael Hartl's new Rails Tutorial Book (3.2), there is a test defined to ensure that if a user is logged in they cannot update (PUT) changes to another user.  If this is attempted, the user should be redirected to the home page.  Because a webpage can't directly issue a PUT, the RSPEC test uses:

before { put user_path(wrong_user) }
{ response.should redirect_to(root_path) }

This test case fails and looking at the log it seems to be exiting on because the first before_filter (signed_in_user) in the UserController is redirecting to the sign in page.

Here is my github page for this sample app:
https://github.com/treetopvt/sample_app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In chapter 8 there was an exercise to switch from cookies to sessions. in my SessionsHelper module I replaced

```
cookies.permanent[:remember_token] = user.remember_token
```

with

```
session[:remember_token] = user.remember_token
```

The move to sessions worked fine, but because I was no longer "permanently" storing a cookie, the test fails.  I undid my exercise changes from Chapter 8, moving back to cookies, and all tests pass.  Now, any ideas on how I change my authorization test to work while using sessions?  This is my current test:

```
            describe "as wrong user" do
            let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
            let(:wrong_user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user, email:"wrong@example.com") }
            before { sign_in user }

            describe "Visiting Users#edit page" do
                before { visit edit_user_path(wrong_user) }
                it { should have_selector('title', text: full_title('')) }
            end

            describe "submitting a PUT request to the Users#update action" do
                before { put user_path(wrong_user) } #put is an update?
                specify{ response.should redirect_to(root_path) }
            end
        end
```

Comment: The author should've mentioned this case for those who did the exercise. Really, it took me hours to solve it. and finally I came over to this answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have your chapters confused, 9.2.1 is about logged out users trying to use the update actions and 9.2.2 is about logged in users trying to use the update actions on other users. You probably need to check your `before` block in your specs to make sure you're testing the correct scenario.

For example: `before { sign_in user }` is used in 9.2.2 to set up a logged in user and then that user will be redirected to the root path when trying to update another user's profile. It looks like you don't have a logged in user at all so the authentication filter stops the flow and redirects to the login page instead.

Comment: You are correct it is 9.2.2. It appears to be a case where the logged in user is not remembered between tests.

Comment: In chapter 8 there was an exercise to switch from cookies to sessions. in my SessionsHelper module I replaced 

    cookies.permanent[:remember_token] = user.remember_token
with

    session[:remember_token] = user.remember_token

The move to sessions worked fine, but because I was no longer "permanently" storing a cookie, the test fails.  I undid my exercise changes from Chapter 8, moving back to cookies, and all tests pass.

Answer (score 0):

Please check this [Stack Overflow comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9960732/rspec-vs-cookies-the-test-fails-even-if-the-applications-works-simulating-lo#comment12727668_9961098). I too faced the same problem and replacing that line in sign_in test helper (as mentioned by "@Aldo 'xoen' Giambelluca" solved the issue. One will face the problem only if one attempted and solved the exercises in chapter 8. It would have been better, as @Hoang Pham noted, if the book mentions that those who did the exercise would face this issue.