# RSpec vs. Cookies - The test fails even if the applications works (simulating logged user)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cookies, rspec, bdd

I'm reading the Michael Hartl's "Ruby on Rails "Turorial" but I'm stuck [here](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/book/ruby-on-rails-tutorial?version=3.1#sec%3arequiring_the_right_user).

I wrote the tests to check user authorization on user edit/update, I've also wrote the controller code and *it works*:

1. If user is not logged and try to access `users#edit` or `users#update` it's redirected to the login page
2. If the user is logged and he try to edit another user is redirected to the root

The problem is in the spec that tests the point 2, I check that sending a PUT request to the `user_path` I'm redirected to the root but running rspec I get the following error:

```
Failures:

  1) Authentication authorization as wrong user submitting a PUT request to users#update 
     Failure/Error: specify { response.should redirect_to(root_url) }
       Expected response to be a redirect to <http://www.example.com/> but was a redirect to <http://www.example.com/signin>
     # ./spec/requests/authentication_pages_spec.rb:73:in `block (5 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

It seems it's redirected to the `signin_url` instead of the `root_url`, like if the user is not logged at all...and this is what I guess cause the problem.

The application store a token in the cookies to authenticate the user.
To test this I wrote an helper method called `signin_user(user)` and put it in the `spec/support/utilities.rb` file:

```
# spec/support/utilities.rb
def sign_in(user)
  visit signin_path
  fill_in "Email", with: user.email
  fill_in "Password", with: user.password
  click_button "Sign in"
  # Make signin work even when not using capybara (e.g. when using get, or post)
  cookies[:remember_token] = user.remember_token 
end
```

As you can see the method set the remember_token cookie to make sure the user is logged even when using `put`, `delete`, etc...or at least it should work!

How can I make this spec pass as it should?

```
# spec/requests/authentication_pages_spec.rb
require 'spec_helper'

describe "Authentication" do
  subject { page }

  # ...

  describe "authorization" do
    # ...

    describe "as wrong user" do
      let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
      let(:another_user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user, email: "another@example.com") }

      before { sign_in(user) }

      # ...

      describe "submitting a PUT request to users#update" do
        before { put user_path(another_user) } 

        specify { response.should redirect_to(root_url) }
      end
    end
  end
end
```

**UPDATE**: And this is my `UsersController`:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :signed_in_user, :only => [:edit, :update]
  before_filter :correct_user, :only => [:edit, :update]

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(params[:user])
    if @user.save
      sign_in @user
      flash[:success] = "Welcome to the sample App!"
      redirect_to @user
    else
      render "new"
    end
  end

  def edit
  end

  def update   
    if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
      sign_in(@user)
      flash[:success] = "Your profile was successfully updated"
      redirect_to @user
    else
      render "edit"
    end
  end

  private
    def signed_in_user
      unless signed_in?
        redirect_to signin_url, notice: "Please sign in to access this page."
      end
    end

    def correct_user
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
      redirect_to root_url unless current_user?(@user)
    end
end
```

Comment: I know you said the controller works, but can you post the code for your users controller anyway? Are you sure both the `edit` *and* `update` actions redirect to `root_url` for your second point?

Comment: @pjumble Thanks for the reply, sure I've updated the question with the UsersController's code. I've tested in the browser and it works.

Comment: @pjumble Ragarding your question, I don't know how to make a PUT request with wget, I've searched in the man page but I've found nothing.

Comment: Are your `current_user`, `signed_in?` and `user_from_remember_token` helper functions all the same as in the book? I tried all of your code from above (with the helpers from the book) and the test passed. Could you push the full code for the project (with failing test) to your github so we can see it all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After looking at the helpers from the rest of the code on your github repository I think I see the problem.

You're using the `session` variable for storing your `:remember_token`:

```
  def user_from_remember_token
    remember_token = session[:remember_token]
    User.find_by_remember_token(remember_token) unless remember_token.nil?
  end
```

The book uses cookies:

```
  def user_from_remember_token
    remember_token = cookies[:remember_token]
    User.find_by_remember_token(remember_token) unless remember_token.nil?
  end
```

Your test helper sets the cookie:

```
# Make signin work even when not using capybara (e.g. when using get, or post)
cookies[:remember_token] = user.remember_token
```

but because your `user_from_remember_token` is looking for `session[:remember_token]` not a cookie, it thinks the user isn't logged in so the test gets redirected to `login_path` instead of `root_path`.

It says why they use a cookie here: http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/sign-in-sign-out?version=3.2#sec:a_working_sign_in_method

---

If you want to continue using a session you would need to adjust your test to sign in via `post` so the `put` has the session set, for example:

```
  describe "submitting a PUT request to users#update" do
    before do 
      post sessions_path, :email => user.email, :password => user.password
      put user_path(another_user)
    end
    specify { response.should redirect_to(root_url) }
  end
```

Comment: You're right, I used session instead of cookies (at lower level both use cookies BTW) but I missed this yesterday. Thank you very much, I'm trying to log the user in the test using your tip (I've some problem but I hope to resolve soon)

Comment: I've tried to submit a POST request directly to the sessions_path as you wrote but I get the same problem. I even tried to replace :session with :parameters but the result it's the same, user seems not logged

Comment: I finally solved the problem and made the user login work even in the tests: I replaced the `cookies[:remember_token] = ...` line in the `sign_in` test helper with `post sessions_path, :email => user.email, :password => user.password` (Note that I passed the parameters directly to `post`)

Comment: thank you very much for your help and sorry for the stupid question!

Comment: I've edited your answer with the right call to post, I hope you don't mind ;)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the answer!  I'm working through the book as well and have the same problem.  The reason for using sessions is that [exercise 2 in section 8.5](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/sign-in-sign-out?version=3.2#sec%3asign_in_out_exercises) is to use session instead of cookies.

My answer is a little different.  My SessionsController uses session variables in the params:

```
  def create
    user = User.find_by_email(params[:session][:email])
    if user && user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
      sign_in user
      redirect_back_or user
    else
      flash.now[:error] = 'Invalid email/password combination'
      render 'new'
    end
  end
```

so the fix is a slightly more complicated:

```
#spec/support/utilities.rb
def sign_in(user)
  visit signin_path
  fill_in "session_email",    with: user.email
  fill_in "session_password", with: user.password
  click_button "Sign in"
  # Sign in when not using Capybara as well.
  post sessions_path, {:session => { :email => user.email, :password => user.password }}
end
```

Comment: You're welcome, I've done this also to avoid session hijacking (I know it's just a sample application and I will not use for real but I've tried to make this little change)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue but a different cause.

I had a typo in spec/support/utilities.rb

```
def sign_in(user)
    visit signin_path
    fill_in "Email",  with: user.email
    fill_in "Password", with: user.password
    click_button "Sign in"
    # Sign in when not using Capybara as well
    cookies[:remember_toke] = user.remember_token
end
```

Note that the last line says ":remember_toke" instead of ":remember_token"

Somehow that caused the test to fail and redirected to signon.

So I am documenting this here in case someone else makes the same type of mistake.

Comment: Thanks, I'm sure someone will find it useful sometime in the future ;)